# How to disable eslint check on development mode in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, eslint, pre-commit

I have configured eslint successfully to run for every commit (pre-commit hook) in reactjs project. It runs properly after sending git commit command to terminal.

here's my `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    ......
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .tsx .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint src --ext .tsx --fix",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.tsx\"",
    ......
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.(ts|tsx)": [
      "prettier --write .",
      "eslint src --ext .tsx --fix .",
      "git add ."
    ]
  },
```

But I don't want eslint to check for rules when in development mode (by running `npm run start`).

For example, I set `no-console` rule to `error` to prevent user to commit the code using `console.log` in it, but when I try to use `console.log` in development mode to show the log in console, it throw an error by lint check

How can I config it?

Thanks all

Comment: Can you provide us your package.json to see how you run the linting phase please?

Comment: @WilliamScalabre I 've modified the original post to add ```package.json``` in it.

Comment: hi all, I'm still waiting answer from you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I myself found the solution from here
Edit .env:

`DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true`

Or in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",
    "test": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be you need just to disable for compilation but not to check in console?

then, either replace `start` script or use a new l-force

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start-force": "ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true react-scripts start",
  }
}
```